# Negative coefficients for DIIS in SCF procedure

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I am trying to implement the direct inversion of the iterative subspace (DIIS) algorithm in my simple HF program. After some problems it now seems to work. I can calculate the correct energies in roughly the same number of steps as in the literature.

My problem is that when generating the Fock matrix from previous Fock matrices I sometimes have negative expansion coefficients. This leads to expansion coefficients for the newest Fock matrix larger than one. The coefficient still sum to one.

Did anyone else encounter this problem?

Comment: I just ran an SCF calculation with DIIS method and I can positively confirm that Fock matrix elements are sometimes greater than 1 or less than -1.  Additionally, MO coefficients can certainly be negative.

Comment: After some further research I came to the conclusion that the DIIS doesnt restrict coefficients to $[0,1]$. This is only true for EDIIS. http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4740249